# crystal - if statement - If field 'a' is blank then look at field 'b'

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi, formulas

In Crystal 11, does the possibility exist to create a statement that would solve this issue I am faced with, using a formula field...

look at {fieldA} if there is a value listed, this should be the result
but if {fieldA} is blank then refer to {fieldB} then use this as the result

Any advice or example statements for me to look at would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
if {fieldA} = "" then {fieldB}
else {fieldA}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to treat `NULL` values as blanks, then this is very straightforward. Simply create a formula field with this:

```
if {fieldA} > "" then {fieldA}
else {fieldB}
```

HOWEVER!! For this to work for NULL values of`{fieldA}` you MUST toggle to "Default Values for NULL option.